# How to count the number of properties in a complex class

Tags: kotlin, avro

I have a class with several properties. The properties, themselves, can also have their own properties. I would like to count the total number of properties. That includes both the properties in the "main" class and the properties' properties.

For instance, consider the following class

```kotlin
class Person {
   val firstname: String =  "Jurgen"
   val lastname: String = "Klopp"
   val address: Address = Address("Liverpool", "England")
}
```

where

```kotlin
class Address (
   val city: String,
   val coubtry: String
) { }
```

I would like the counting to add up to `5`, since the `Person` class "contains" `firstname`, `lastname`, `address`, `city` and `country`. Note that the `Address` class also could have a another class (with its own properties) as its property. These properties should also be counted. Is it possible to count the total number of properties?

Please further note that the counting is intended to be applied to complex/multi-leveled AVRO structures (i.e. auto-generated AVRO classes).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34547103/11107541 for how to use reflection to list fields of a class.

Comment: There's a lot of different approaches to this, depending on what your goal and constraints are. Can you explain more? Do you want to do this at compile time, or run time? You mention Avro - have you tried using Kotlinx Serialization and a [3rd party Avro library](https://github.com/avro-kotlin/avro4k)? What about [KSP](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm basing this off my other post on reflection, found here: [How to get the relative class name of data classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547691/how-to-get-the-relative-class-name-of-data-classes/72731402#72731402)

I created your two classes in a package called `complexclasses`.

My `Main.kt` looks like this:

```kotlin
import complexclasses.Person
import kotlin.reflect.KClass
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val foundParams = Person::class.getAllMembers()
    println(foundParams)
}

private fun KClass<*>.getAllMembers(): MutableList<String> {
    val params = mutableListOf<String>()
    memberProperties.forEach { member ->
        params.add(member.name)
        if(member.returnType.toString().substring(0, 7) == "kotlin.") {
            return@forEach
        }
        val clazz = Class.forName(member.returnType.toString()).kotlin
        params.addAll(clazz.getAllMembers())
    }
    return params
}
```

When I run the program, it outputs:

```
[address, city, country, firstname, lastname]
```

Using reflection (and a little string manipulation) I can recursively crawl non-kotlin objects and print out the names of all their members.

I didn't test this with more complicated data structures, like `List`s or `Map`s. It's possible those would require more work, but I think this is enough to get you started, at least.

I'm not familiar with AVRO so hopefully this works with it.

Let me know if you hit any issues, I'm glad to help if this doesn't meet your requirements.